# R: Extracting the last few digits from a vector of characters

Tags: r

In a data frame, one of the columns is textual data which looks like:

```
df <- data.frame("Index" = 1:3, "Content" = c("Happy 2021! word count: 2",
"Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. Today is a good day. word count:100",
"Thank you very much for your time. word count: 7"))
```

The last several characters are always  "word count: n". I hope to extra the n and put it into a new column.

I have tried to write a function to do so

```
wordCount = function (x) {
  digit = -1
  while(is.numeric(str_sub(essay$content,digit，-1))){
    digit = digit -1
  }
  str_sub(essay$content,digit，-1)
}
```

But it doesn't work because is.numeric(str_sub(essay$content,digit，-1)) always returns false since this column is treated as characters by R.

Does anyone have a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `stringi::stri_extract_last_regex` to get the last numbers with a number-matching regex pattern. This should work:

```
library(stringi)
df$word_count = as.numeric(stri_extract_last_regex(df$Content, "[0-9]+"))
df["word_count"]
#   word_count
# 1          2
# 2        100
# 3          7
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but I get an error "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, word_count, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1".

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

In base `R` you can use:

```
as.numeric(gsub(".*:", "", df$Content))
```